# Marshall struct with char

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

When marshalling struct which contains a single char field from C++ to C# how the C# struct definition should look like?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1), Serializable]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public sbyte Field;
}
```

or

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1), Serializable]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte Field;
}
```

I can't find a clear info about should it be a signed byte or not. (It is declared as 'char' in C++ struct definition)

UPD: Does It depends on whether C++ lib was build with GCC or VS (default compiler options)? If not, can I hope 'char' is signed on both GCC and VS (default compiler options)

Comment: Is the field actually a character, or it it just something else stuffed into the convenient 8-bit type which happened to be called char?

Comment: It's used to store small ints in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, in general, tell if `char` is signed or unsigned in C++. It depends on the implementation, and a single compiler (implementation) can often be configured through options to make it either way.

The best choice would be to make it explicit in the C++ code if possible, i.e. use `signed char` or `unsigned char`. Then you can pick `sbyte` or `byte` for the C# marshalling as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio and GCC, `char` is [signed by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default/2054959#2054959). The [/J](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d294k5z.aspx) compiler option (`-funsigned-char` for GCC) can be used to make it unsigned.

So the answer depends on whether or not that option is used in your C++ project.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you prefer to store the value in C#.  You should choose whichever is most convenient.

- If you store it in your C# variable as an unsigned value, then marshal it as `UnmanagedType.U1`.
- If you store it in your C# variable as a signed value, then marshal it as `UnmanagedType.I1`.

The point being that once that byte crosses the module boundary it's the bitwise representation that matters and not the logical representation in the C# code.  An unsigned value of 255 is equivalent to a signed value of -1 once you have reached the C++ code.

---

Of course, this assumes that you are using `char` as a character type.  In a comment to the question you state that you are using it as a integer type, in which case you need to decide whether or not it is signed and marshal accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this, seems that my answer Is now just about C++ char specification...